# Why can't NSDateFormatter convert string correctly

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using the following code to convert an `NSString` to an `NSDate`:

```
+(NSDate *)dateOfDateTimeString:(NSString *)string {

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd_HH:mm aa"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];

    NSLog(@"try to convert string: %@ to date: %@", string, date);

    return date;
}
```

However I am getting unexpected results:

> 2012-06-14 22:26:59.208 Motilink[2223:707] +[NSDate(Util) dateOfDateTimeString:][Line 117] try to convert string:
>
> 2012.06.12_21:26 PM to date: 2012-06-12 03:26:00 +0000
>
> 2012-06-14 22:26:59.226 Motilink[2223:707] +[NSDate(Util) dateOfDateTimeString:][Line 117] try to convert string:
>
> 2012.06.13_15:00 PM to date: 2012-06-13 03:00:00 +0000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, but it looks like you have different date formats.  You would need a different dateFormat for each of these.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 21:26 PM. Either go for 9:26 PM or skip the "aa" part in your format.